# Sprite movement based on rotation

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation

I have a sprite in Android OpenGL. This sprite (a small beetlebug) is always moving in a forward direction and I use:

```
sprite.setPosition(posX, posY);
```

Now I have a rotation method, when the user gestures left or right the bug rotates:

```
private void applyRotation() {
    for(int i=0;i<beetleBug.size;i++) {
         Sprite s = beetleBug.get(i);
         s.setOrigin(s.getWidth() / 2, s.getHeight() / 2);
         s.setRotation(angle);
     }
}
```

Now when the bug is moving forward which he always does the new x and y coordinates have to be calculated which depend on the rotation-angle, so that the bug is always moving forward. Does anybody have an algorithm to calculate the direction by the rotation-angle?

Here is the whole Bug-class:

```
public class Bug {

    private SpriteBatch             spriteBatch = null;
    private TextureAtlas            spriteSheet;
    private Array<Sprite>           beetleBug;
    private int                     currentFrame = 0;
    private final float             frameLength = 0.10f;    //in seconds, how long a frame last
    private float                   animationElapsed = 0.0f;
    private float                   angle = 0.0f;
    private float                   posX = 0.0f;
    private float                   posY = 0.0f;
    private float                   sizeX = 100.0f;
    private float                   sizeY = 100.0f;
    private float                   offSet = 50.0f;

    public Bug() {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        spriteSheet = new TextureAtlas("assets/data/bug.txt");
        beetleBug = spriteSheet.createSprites("bug");

        // dont forget to set the size of your sprites!
        for(int i=0; i<beetleBug.size; i++){
            beetleBug.get(i).setSize(sizeX, sizeY);

        }

        applyPosition();
    }



    public void handleInput() {

        boolean leftKey = Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT);
        boolean rightKey = Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT);

        if(rightKey) {
            if(angle <= 0) {
                angle = 360;
            }
            angle -= 2f;
            applyRotation();
        }

        if(leftKey) {
            if(angle >= 360) {
                angle = 0;
            }
            angle += 2f;
            applyRotation();
        }


        applyPosition();
    }


    private void applyPosition() {
        float x = (float) Math.cos(angle);
        float y = (float) Math.sin(angle);

        posX = posX + x;
        posY = posY + y;

        for(int i=0; i<beetleBug.size; i++){
            beetleBug.get(i).setPosition(posX - offSet, posY -offSet); // optional: center the sprite to screen
        }   
    }


    private void applyRotation() {
        for(int i=0;i<beetleBug.size;i++) {
             Sprite s = beetleBug.get(i);
             s.setOrigin(s.getWidth() / 2, s.getHeight() / 2);
             s.setRotation(angle);
         }
    }

    public void render(OrthographicCamera cam) {

        float dt = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        animationElapsed += dt;
        while(animationElapsed > frameLength){
            animationElapsed -= frameLength;
            currentFrame = (currentFrame == beetleBug.size - 1) ? 0 : ++currentFrame;
        }

        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        spriteBatch.begin();
        beetleBug.get(currentFrame).draw(spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
int currentX = 100; //beetleCurrentX
int currentY = 100; //beetleCurrentY
int angle = 200;    //beetleAngle
int len = 2;        //Step that the beetle makes (jumps 2 in this case)

int x2Pos = sin(angle)*len + currentX;
int y2Pos = cos(angle)*len + currentY;

sprite.setPosition(x2Pos,y2Pos);
```

If you execute this each frame you will have your beetle moving in the angles direction.

Comment: Please see the whole Bug-class above, it does not work this way, the beetlebug is rotating but always moveing n wrong directions after every key-input.

Comment: Note that this will be for zero degrees pointing in the positive y direction, with the angle increasing as it goes clockwise. e.g. compass points

Answer (score 1):

Create a normalized vector to represent the beetle's direction, then multiply by the speed. Add that vector to the beetle's current position and you've got his new position.

1. Create the normalized vector (i.e. has a length of 1) using your angle. `vx = cos(angle), vy = sin(angle)`
2. Multiply by your beetle's speed. `vx = vx*speed, vy = vy*speed`
3. Add it to the current position. `x = x + vx, y = y + vy`
4. Repeat

Some gotchas: Watch out that your sprite's graphical rotation and your own internal representation of rotation go the same way. Some frameworks flip which way they rotate graphics. The above [cos(angle), sin(angle)] is for an angle of zero pointing towards the positive x axis. Many implementations of cos/sin/tan use radians instead of degrees for their calculations, so convert as appropriate.

`[cos angle, sin angle]`is for zero to the right (positive x), counterclockwise. `[-sin angle, cos angle]`is for zero pointing up (positive y), counterclockwise.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be this way: When I press right key I have to decrease the angle, how can I woraround this cause setting the direction with sin and cos does not work correctly.

Comment: Two big headaches to look out for: 1) Make sure the direction that your sprite faces at zero degrees is what you are coding to be zero degrees. Is that up, right, etc.? 2) Is your framework's rotations in degrees (0-360) or radians (0-2pi)? This includes the sin/cos calls in particular. They are probably radian-based.

Comment: 1) This is given. 0 degrees is the starting-rotation. 2) The angle is in degrees not radians. Thanks for this point, I think Ihave to convert to radians.

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly now:

1. Converted degrees to radians
2. Set x-coordintae to -

   private void applyPosition() {

   ```
   float radians =  (float) Math.toRadians(angle);
   float x = -(float) Math.sin(radians);
   float y = (float) Math.cos(radians);

   posX = posX + x;
   posY = posY + y;

   for(int i=0; i<beetleBug.size; i++){
       beetleBug.get(i).setPosition(posX - offSet, posY -offSet); 
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: My bad for copying my function from c++ really, thought sin would auto convert to radians.

Comment: The reason you have to invert the x coordinate is because your 0 degrees is pointed up, instead of the right. i.e. the direction of the x-axis. `[-sin a, cos a]` is for zero pointing up (positive y), counterclockwise. `[cos a, sin a]` is for zero to the right (positive x), counterclockwise.